# Installing MySQL+Smarty

Tags: apache-2.2, linuxmint

I'd like to start learning WWW-programming in my Linux Mint. I have installed PHP and now I'd like to install MySQL. I tried to follow instructions on http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-mysql-server-5-on-ubuntu-linux/ but I got the following error message:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2
apache2:    Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

... waiting .apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I install Smarty on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable ServerName in your http.conf file. When a name isn't defined apache uses 127.0.0.1(loopback) address as the server name.

This is not an error and apache is running despite through these.

Comment: Strange. It looks like I don't have http.conf in my computer.

Comment: Linux Mint is Ubuntu based, meaning your config file will be /etc/apache2/apache.conf.

Comment: So, you can find `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: Okay. Now I added lines # This would be correct.
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName some.domain.com
  # Options and stuff defined here.
</VirtualHost> which I found by Google. But it still won't work.